# how hidden Bottom Tabs Navigator in React native Navigation V6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I used [React Navigation V6](https://reactnavigation.org) in **React Native**
The page1 is my login page where I need to hide the **tab bar bottom** on this page and some pages.
But this code does not work for me
Can you Help me what the problem ?
Thankful

[snack expo Code](https://snack.expo.dev/@mohammad_askarzadeh/stack-navigator-%7C-react-navigation)

```
  function MainStackScreen({route, navigation }) {

    //  if (route.state &&  route.state.index == 0) {
      if (route.state && route.state.routes[route.state.index].name == "Page1") {
          navigation.setOptions( {tabBarVisible: false});
          Alert.alert("OK");
      
      } else {
        navigation.setOptions( {tabBarVisible: true});
        Alert.alert("NO");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8981

In V6 tabBarVisible option has been removed. If you want hide tab bottom in your auth screen you should try this way:

```
{auth ? <Root/> : <Auth/>} in App.js
```

`<Root/>`: your app with all screens have tab bottom

`<Auth/>`: only sign & sign up with Stack.Screen